# Kerberos authentication in ios 6.0 and older

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios5, ios6

I want to authenticate the user to enterprise AD using Kerberos. I have found GSS API is available from iOS 5.0. However unable to locate a sample or blog or tutorial regarding its usage and success. Any pointers will be useful.
I know in iOS 7.0 we can use SSO with Kerberos but I am not looking at that.

Also If you know another way to do the same. Please share.